# please help me find where is error? R language

Tags: r

I'm writing an SI Model using the deSolve package for R.The model describes the transmission of an infection within a community and then allows the introduction of external events - which represent the mass treatment of the whole community. The final graph should show the three curves of "Susceptible", "Infected", and "Total". But the output chart is wrong. I don't know where the problem is. the debug could run without any error pops up. there is no Infected and total line in the graph, and susceptible is wrong too. the first image is How the code runs out. but what I need should be like the second image.
[image: wrong graph] and [image: It should looks like this]

```
rm(list=ls())
require(deSolve) 
odeequations=function(t,y,pars) {     
  S=y[1]; In=y[2]; 
  beta=pars[1];   
  dS= -beta*S*In;  
  dIn=beta*S*In;  
  return(list(c(dS,dIn))); 
}  
S0=1;                   
I0=100000;
Y0=c(S0, I0);   
tmax=70; 
dt=1; 
timevec=seq(0,tmax,dt);  
beta=1.5; 
pars=c(beta);
odeoutput=lsoda(Y0,timevec,odeequations,parms=pars, atol=1e-7,rtol=1e-7);
## windows(width=10,height=10)
plot(odeoutput[,1],odeoutput[,2],type="l",xlab="time (years)",ylab="",col="green",lwd=2,log="",xlim=c(0,tmax),ylim=c(1,max(odeoutput[,2])),main="Outbreak Time Series")
lines(odeoutput[,1],odeoutput[,3],type="l",col="red",lwd=2)
lines(odeoutput[,1],odeoutput[,2]+odeoutput[,3], type="l",col="blue",lwd=2)
legend("right", c("Susceptible","Infected","Total"),col = c("green","red","blue"),lwd=2)
```

Comment: How is the output chart wrong? what does it show instead? have you tried debugging by running the code line by line to see where the error pops up?

Comment: the debug could run without any error pops up. there is no Infected and total line in the graph. It should be three lines in the graph, but I only got one. I add two different images.  thanks

Comment: The model given has only 2 state variables, so you cannot expect 3 curves. Besides this, there may be some other problems, Instead of fixing this code, I recommend to start from one of the many avalable examples.

Answer (score 1):

A general SIR model with **deSolve** is found at different places, for example in the following paper: https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v033.i03

A SEIR model (i.e. with an additional state variable) can be formulated as follows:

```
library("deSolve")

SEIR <- function(t, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(parms, y)), {
    dS <- -rho * beta * I * S
    dE <-  rho * beta * S * I - alpha * E
    dI <-  alpha * E - gamma * I
    dR <-  gamma * I
    list(c(dS, dE, dI, dR))
  })
}

# state variables: fractions of total population
y0 <- c(S=1 - 5e-4,       # susceptible
        E=4e-4,           # exposed
        I=1e-4,           # infected
        R=0)              # recovered or deceased

parms  <- c(alpha = 0.2,  # inverse of incubation period (5 days)
            beta = 1.75,  # average contact rate
            gamma = 0.5,  # inverse of mean infectious period (2 days)
            rho = 1)      # social distancing factor (0 ... 1)

# time in days
times <- seq(0, 150, 1)

# numerical integration
out <- ode(y0, times, SEIR, parms, method="bdf", atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-8)
matplot.0D(out)
```

This example and several links to other versions can be found at https://github.com/tpetzoldt/covid

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your code.

- you have `S0` and `I0` switched (i.e., try setting `S0 <- 1e5; I0 <- 1` rather than vice versa)
- your `beta` value is way too high; try `beta <- 1.5/1e5` (i.e., scale by population size)